# Redact rep and vote count

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

```js
/* ==UserStyle==
@name           Hide Rep
@namespace      github.com/openstyles/stylus
@version        1.0.0
@description    Hide the reputation of users.
@author         Me
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com"), domain("mathoverflow.net") {
.reputation-score, .badge1, .badge2, .badge3, .badgecount, .s-user-card--rep, .js-header-rep, .rep-score, .js-vote-count {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

### About

Is your vote biased by reputation count? Do you feel inclined to accept an answer with lots of upvotes? Eradicate the bias with this userscript!

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

## [Download Here.](https://userstyles.world/style/10285/hide-rep-and-vote-count)

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome with Stylus

### Contact

I created this code. My GitHub username is PlaceReporter99.

### Code

I Used a userscript manager called Stylus. Source code should be obtainable from download link.